# Why can't my jar see the HBase configuration from the environment?

Tags: scala, hadoop, jvm, classpath, hbase

I wrote an application that tried to create a default HBaseConfiguration, but when I package the application as a jar it won't work properly because it is trying to use 127.0.0.1's zookeeper and not the one specified in my `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml`.  The application can be stripped down to something like this:

```
 object TestUtil extends App {
   val hbaseTable = new HTable(HBaseConfiguration.create, "tableName")
   println(hbaseTable)
 }
```

When I run this using the following command it works fine:

```
 CLASSPATH=`hbase classpath` java fully.qualified.name.TestUtil
```

If I package it as a jar and call it using `CLASSPATH='hbase classpath' java -jar TestUtil.jar` then I get the following error:

```
 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: HBase is able to connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately.
```

I've checked the logs and can see that it is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 for Zookeeper, which is different from the zookeeper configuration in my `/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml`.  The jar seems to be ignoring my classpath even though I explicitly set it on the command line.

How can I make the JVM honor my classpath when executing a jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When starting a JVM with `java -jar` the resulting environment does not see files in the classpath from the outside `CLASSPATH` variable.  It instead uses the [classpath from the MANIFEST file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Assuming you don't want to hardcode the paths to your dependencies in the manifest, You can get around this by:

1. putting the JAR you want to run in the class path in addition to,
2. not using the `-jar` switch, and
3. specifying the class with the `main()` as an argument.

For example:

```
 CLASSPATH=/path/to/my.jar:`hbase classpath` java fully.qualified.MainClass
```

This is the same approach that HBase's `hbase` shell script uses.  Take a look at [line 332](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hbase/trunk/bin/hbase?revision=1296661&view=markup).

So long as your JAR doesn't include an `hbase-site.xml`, this approach should result in the JVM loading the `hbase-site.xml` from your classpath.